# I can't access my views of my application through browser

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, https, production-environment

I'm trying to publish and run my application in the production environment . the home page opens fine but I can't access the rest of the views . It always redirects to the error page.
I changed the webpage:Enabled from false to true in the web.config `<add key="webpages:Enabled" value="true" />` but the same issue still exists.
What am i missing?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Looks like some of the handlers are not working as expected at the server. Please check with your server admin to see all pre-requisites are in place.

Comment: Disable custom errors then it will show more detail about the error.